# Generate Linq dynamically but throw exception when string[] is null

Tags: c#, linq

```
 int id = 1;
 string[] employerNos = null;
 var query = from y in mydb.myTable
             where y.ID == id
             && (employerNos == null ? true : employerNos.Contains(y.EmpNo))                             
             select y;
 var result = query.ToList();
```

The string array is null so I think the statement should be true. I don't know why it throws System.NotSupportedException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your query is not LINQ to Objects, so your LINQ query provider has to translate both parts of conditional statement into correct SQL code.

Instead of including condition within query take it out of it:

```
int id = 1;
string[] employerNos = null;

var query = mydb.MyTable.Where(y => y.ID == id)
if(employerNos != null)
    query = query.Where(y => employerNos.Contains(y.EmpNo))

var result = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to translate that expression into SQL. I believe the problem is that you can't pass a list of strings as a parameter.

so

```
var query = from y in mydb.myTable
            where y.ID == id
            && employerNos.Contains(y.EmpNo))                             
            select y;
```

Would translate to something like

```
select * from myTable
where ID=@ID
and EmpNo in ('1','3','5') -- employerNos evaluated before translation to sql
```

But if you try your query with the null check, you get something like

```
select * from myTable
where ID=@ID
and (@list is null 
    or EmpNo in @list)  -- this bit is not valid SQL
```

You can do something like this instead.

```
var query = 
    from y in mydb.myTable
    where y.ID == id
    select y;

if (employerNos != null) 
    query = query.Where(y => employerNos.Contains(y.EmpNo))
```